# Efficient algorithm to aggregate a heightmap to a lower resolution

Tags: algorithm, heightmap

I have a raw 2D height map which consists of cells of the following structure:

```
type Cell =    
{ Coordinate: GeoCoordinate //contains Latitude and Longitude of the coordinate
  Elevation: int16
}
```

I generate this height map from real world data.

Now I want to aggregate the height map to a lower resolution, say from a cell grid length of 300 meters to 10 kilometers. That is, creating an average of the elevations. Of course, I can apply a brute force algorithm to do so, e.g. beginning from the center cell grid and aggregate it to a "bigger cell grid", memorizing which grids have been considered, and so forth. But maybe this is not the best way of doing that. Are there more efficient ways (algorithms) for aggregating such a height map?

Comment: You may want to look into [Summed Area Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table).

Comment: oh cool, was not aware of this, thanks!. You may add this as answer if you want :)

Comment: Mipmapping is supported in GPU hardware i.e. you don't have to do the work yourself. And it is extremely fast at such resolution-reductions.

Comment: I do not need it during runtime of the game. So GPU might be overkill...(effort developing it)

Comment: You don't have to develop it. The GPU does it for you automatically.

Comment: [Mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)

Comment: Ok, thanks, will have a look. I am using MonoGame.

Comment: I'm reading this again and again and I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you provide an example or a clearer explanation?

Comment: @gronostaj you have a 2D height map, now you want to zoom out (like with any other map), to achieve this, you want to lower the resolution of the height map, see answer and the link concerning Mipmapping.

Comment: So you're essentially asking how to resize an image. Mipmapping is a particular implementation of that.

Comment: Will mipmapping preserve the range?  If the height map is used for geometry might one want to make sure that the highest and lowest points remain the same?  But there would be no such expectation with a mipmap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) is the way to do this. The algorithm already exists in hardware and it is extremely fast since GPUs are massively parallel devices.

All you need to do is set up a 3D context in something like MonoGame, LibGDX, or Unity, and have the GPU do the work for you. So you don't need to write any algorithms.